# Building a SQL UPDATE command by knowing the SELECT command?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-update

Let's say that's my select query:

```
SELECT
    CNDSC.NAME,
    CNEA.ATRBT AS ATR,
    ISNULL(CNEXTRA.CNVAL,'') AS CNVAL,
    ISNULL(CNEXTRA.INRDR,'') AS INRDR
FROM
    CNDSC
    INNER JOIN CNEA
        ON CNEA.ELEMS LIKE '%'+CAST(CNDSC.FNCELEM AS VARCHAR)+'%' AND
           NOT CNEA.ELEMS LIKE '%1'+CAST(CNDSC.FNCELEM AS VARCHAR)+'%'  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CNEXTRA
        ON CNEXTRA.ATR LIKE CNEA.ATRBT AND
           CNEXTRA.NAME LIKE @con
WHERE
    CNDSC.NAME LIKE @con;
```

I am using C# to bind the result of that query on a datagrid. But when I try using the "auto-update" command of the SQLDataAdapter, I get an exception due to the use of more than one table in my select.

How would the UPDATE command look like, if I wanted to UPDATE the CNEXTRA.CNVAL table? And how could I ensure, if the CNVAL is empty that I will have to use the INSERT command?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Which SQL server (MSSQL, Oracle, ???) In MS SQL Server, some join-based view definitions will allow you to perform updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your version of SQL server you can use [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) instead of UPDATE.

Something like:

```
DECLARE @CNVAL varchar(100) = 'test'
DECLARE @ATRBT varchar(100) = 'some attribute'
DECLARE @CON varchar(100) = 'the name'

MERGE into CNEXTRA as target
  USING ( VALUES( @CON, @ATRBT, @CNVAL))
      AS source([Name], ATRBT, CNVAL)
      ON (target.ATRBT = source.ATRBT)
      AND (target.[Name] = source.[Name])
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET
        CNVAL = source.CNVAL
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT([Name], ATRBT, CNVAL)
     VALUES(source.[Name], source.ATRBT, source.CNVAL)
;
```

A [MERGE statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) will perform an update if the record exists or an insert if it doesn't.

Comment: Unfortunately the MSSQL server doesn't support the MERGE command... Is there any other chance to realise this?

Comment: @Forlan07: your next best bet is to write a select statement to see if the record exists and then decide whether to do a regular insert or update from there.

Comment: Ok, I changed the compatibility level of my db to 100, so this command works. But for some reason, if I update the CNVAL, the command will update every column, where the ATRBT is set. So the statement doesn't check whether CON equals target.Name? How can that be possible?

Comment: Could it also be possible that I lose some data when not using the tables used in my joins?

Comment: @Forlan07: post your actual table structures with a bit of sample data.

Comment: I will post the structures tomorrow

Comment: I finally found the mistake... Your merge command was correct... I got some strange data in my database.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code but something like this should work... (but you'll need to write your own insert, update and delete queries)

```
public static DataSet UpdateSqlRows(
    string connectionString, 
    string selectQuery,
    string insertQuery,
    string updateQuery,
    string deleteQuery,
    DataSet dataSet)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);

            connection.Open();

            SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

            // Assign your own Insert/Update/Delete commands
            adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand( insertQuery );
            adapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand( updateQuery );
            adapter.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand( deleteQuery );

            //Without the SqlCommandBuilder this line would fail
            adapter.Update(dataSet);

            return dataSet;
        }
    }
}
```